# Very slow to boot takes 9 minutes after upgrade to 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: boot, upgrade, 18.04

So sad I pushed the button to upgrade to 18.04 on my old Acer Aspire laptop with Intel Core 2 Duo T1800 CPU. Now it takes over 9 minutes for it to boot. Some apps were also very slow to load taking 5 minutes. 
I did a fresh full install of 16.04 and still was very slow to boot. I had to do a full install of 14.04 before the laptop was back booting very quickly as expected with a Ubuntu OS.

I see all the other answers that require coding to fix bugs, I have no idea how to do any of that. Am I stuck forever with 14.04 on this old machine? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ubuntu memory requirement probably have increased over the years, how much memory does your machine has? Is it using a conventional HDD?

Comment: It has 2GB of memory and a 120GB SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Lubuntu and Xubuntu releases, those will use less memory than the full Ubuntu release.